# Nott getting same result when trying to get slope from 2 points

Tags: python-3.x, math

I'm trying to make something that would give me the slope and y-intercept from 2 points. Sometimes it would give me the correct values, but other times it would give me something close to correct but wrong.

Anyone know any thing that I could have done wrong? (Also, I feel like I should say that I'm just now starting to learn python)

```
y2 = input('Y2: ')
y1 = input('Y1: ')
x2 = input('X2: ')
x1 = input('X1: ')

y2 = float(y2)
y1 = float(y1)
x2 = float(x2)
x1 = float(x1)

over = y2-y1
under = x2-x1

m = over/under

y = float(y2)
x = float(x2)
m = float(m)

ym = y-m
b = ym/x

print(f'Y = {m}x + {b}')
```

Comment: The only main thing different between the sets of inputs (besides the value of the inputted numbers) is that one set was negative. I only tried 2 different sets of numbers, so I don't have that much of an idea of what changes

Comment: The mathematics appear to be incorrect. the intercept, `b = y1 - mx1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears as though the mathematics for the intercept `b` is incorrect.

it would be logical to use the `x1, y1` coordinate with the slope to generate `b`.

assume that you want to find `x0, y0` where `y0` = `b`. Then you would do a similar calculation (already having calculated `m` before as you correctly did).

So `(y1-b) / x1 = m`. and you can just rearrange this to get:
`b = y1 - m*x1`.

So this works:

```py
x1, y1 = 1, 1
x2, y2 = 2, 2

over = y2-y1
under = x2-x1

m = over/under

b = y1 - m*x1

print(f'Y = {m}x + {b}')
```

returns this:

```
Y = 1.0x + 0.0
```